# Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are premium license user for google maps(so instead of api you will see "client=gme-XXXXXX") and I started seeing this warning recently.

Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Here is the src we use(client name marked as xxxxxxxx)
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?%26client=gme-xxxxxxxx%26sensor=true%26v=3

I went through documentation and couldn't find an answer for users with premium plan, Any pointers why this is happening is appreciated.

Comment: If you have a premium license, you have support from Google.  Try their support portal.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove HTML encoded reference and replace with regular characters in the src link:
From :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?%26client=gme-xxxxxxxx%26sensor=true%26v=3

To: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=gme-xxxxxxxx&v=3